How to preLoad an image format from the cache and get it later by UID from cache using Coil/Glide
That's say I have a data class from the server in the data layer
data class AvatarPreload(
   val base64: String,
   val uid: Long
)

Then I want to save it into my disk/memory, because the View layer shoudn't need to know the base64 and also base64 is too heavy to carry
on
// persudo code
val rq = ImageRequest.Builder(context).data(avatarPreload).memoryCacheKey(avatarPreload.uid.toLong()).build()
context.imageLoader.execute(rq)

Then I'll shrink the data class to a smaller one
data class AvatarForView(
    val uid: Long
)

But I don't know how to get the image only by uid, any Glide/Coil solution will be fine
// persudo code, I want to use uid to get the preload image
val rq = ImageRequest.Builder(context).data(avatarForView.uid).build()
context.imageLoader.execute(rq)

Thanks!!!

I found the way to achieve this,
So first, change the base64 string to bitmap and save it as follow
val request = ImageRequest.Builder(context)
.data(bitmap)
.memoryCacheKey(uid.toString()) 
.diskCacheKey(uid.toString())
.build()

Then, trigger the request by set the data function with empty string e.g. data("")
val request = ImageRequest.Builder(context)
.data("") // This is the key step
.memoryCacheKey(uid.toString())
.diskCacheKey(uid.toString())
.target(object: Target {
  // do the work here
})

because by using this method, it cannot trigger .tranformation() effect, so I have edit my bitmap at .target() step
